# Invalid operands of types 'std::istream*' and 'char' to binary 'operator>>'

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a rudimentary function:

```
TokenType getToken(istream *in, string& recognized){
    char token;
    in >> token;
    if (token=='#'){
        in.ignore('\n');
        in >> token;
    }
    return T_UNKNOWN;
}
```

(`TokenType` is just an enum.)

For some reason, both of the `in >> token;` lines give me this error when compiled with G++:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’ and ‘char’ to binary ‘operator>>’
```

Why is the compiler is throwing this error? I want to be able to extract one `char` from the stream that `in` is pointing to, then skip to the next line if that `char` is a pound sign.

For the sake of posterity, my includes:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
```

Comment: Why not just take a `std::istream &`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dereference your istream pointer

```
(*in) >> token;

in->ignore('\n');
```

Or change in to a reference rather than a pointer.

```
TokenType getToken(istream & in, string& recognized);
```

You would have to change how you call the function by dereferencing the pointer.

```
 getToken(*in, recognized);
```

As 0x499602D2 also points out, using `in->ignore('\n');` does not make sense for your usage, you would want to use:

```
in->ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Which will ignore up to the maximum stream size in characters until a new line character is found.

Comment: `in->ignore('\n')` in his code doesn't make any sense. I think he mean `in->ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`.

Comment: Would dereferencing the pointer cause strange things to happen if the function was called an arbitrary amount of times? Say, if the pointer was pointing to an `ifstream` and the function was being called from a `while (!file.eof())` loop, would that leave an infinite loop?

Comment: The pointer should still point to the `ifstream` object regardless of if you call it while in a loop.

Comment: @MowDownJoe And of course, there is no context where you would ever write `while ( !file.eof() )`.  It just doesn't make any sense.